# Android EditText inputType not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to capitalize first letter of each word but the input type is not working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?
Here is my xml snippet:

```
      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:inputType="text|textCapWords"/>
```

Comment: Check my below solution...If it will not work than message me in these chain

Comment: this is not working.

Comment: Ok,please wait..let me try...soon will post answer

Comment: Try using `android:inputType="textCapSentences" `

Answer (score -2):

I am not programming android apps a lot, but shouldn't you just leave `android:inputType="textCapWords"`
instead of `android:inputType="text|textCapWords"` ?

Answer (score -2):

This will be helpful

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

Answer (score -2):

This solution worked for me, and will definately work for you as well.

Create one static method and pass your editText inside it. And its done.

```
public static void setCapitalizeTextWatcher(final EditText editText) {
        final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            int mStart = 0;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mStart = start + count;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String input = s.toString();
                String capitalizedText;
                if (input.length() < 1)
                    capitalizedText = input;
                else
                    capitalizedText = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
                if (!capitalizedText.equals(editText.getText().toString())) {
                    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            editText.setSelection(mStart);
                            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        }
                    });
                    editText.setText(capitalizedText);
                }
            }
        };

        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }
```

All you need is to call this method when you are finding your edittext and pass your editText in parameter.

Comment: What the actual F

Answer (score -3):

you can use Set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` on your EditText.

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>
```

**Description:**
textCapSentences Can be combined with text and its variations to request capitalization of the first character of every sentence. Corresponds to TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES.

Comment: Question was about capitalizing every word, not just first word in the sentence.